# Push power assisted trolley with one finger

Tags: power, motor, control

I recently saw a demo. One man pushed a power-assisted trolley using only one finger. The trolley was loaded with ~40kg stuff and it started from standstill on a up-slope when the man pushed it using one finger and apparently without much effort and it could move up quite swiftly. I was told there was no force or proximity sensor to detect the finger, but solely depend the motor encoder and controller. I didn't understand how a trolley loaded with 40kg and pushed by a finger could cause any change in the motor's encoder. Did anyone ever worked on power assisted trolley or bike or something else before to understand how to realize it?

Comment: The device in the video is quite different from the impression given in your question. If that is what you mean you need to amend the question-description. The term "trolley" can be used for a 2 wheeled device but is traditionally one which is self stable - 3 or 4 wheels. 
| [**Power assisted trolley gets you these**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1536&bih=826&q=trolley&oq=trolley&gs_l=img.3..0l10.3520.5141.0.5582.7.7.0.0.0.0.298.1313.0j1j5.6.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.62.img..1.6.1313.qpJPrLab0PU#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=trolley+power+assisted)

Comment: The two wheeled "trolley" explicitly explains how it works. If you can clarify your description it would help. | FWIW a "switch" or similar can be entirely invisible to normal examination.

Answer (score 1):

The answer they gave was probably misleading.

One method, and it is very likely that the one used is generally similar, is to have a "position control" lever that is spring loaded to centre. The lever is vertical and spring loaded to the vertical centre position.  If you push on the lever from behind it moves forwards and the system is designed to move the cart forwards until the lever is again vertical. If the pushing "finger" is stationary the cart will move away until the prior condition again exists. If the finger (and the attached person) moves forwards at a steady space the cart can be arranged to move at that pace.

The biggest challenge is probably to get a control loop such that the cart neither "shoots away" when the lever is slightly pressed or stops topo suddenly (or moves backwards once pressure is taken off the lever. The user's brain is probably part of thge control loop - getting the cart to move at desired speed up a slope or down a slope probably requires experience in just how hard and fast to push.

Arrangements like this have been "common enough" for a very long time. Rather than a lever they may use a control plate or a "cord" that the user pulls on and the cart follows. These may operate with a caternerary loop (cord hanging in a downwards loop) so the user exerts almost no force at all.

Comment: I am afraid it is not what you described. The video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NpV23k1UUE shows very similar one, at 0:07 and 1:02, you can see how the cart can be pushed with one finger. Of course the one I saw was different design and carried much more stuff. So I don't think there would be a secret lever somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the video you linked it sounds like an inverted pendulum control system, similar to a Segway. When you push on the top of the inverted pendulum the wheels move to bring the CG overtop so that is balanced. This is a closed-loop control system.

I've never ridden a Segway but I tried a Chinese ATV version recently- as Russell says there is significant interaction between the machine's control system and your own so there is a learning process if you're actally aboard such a beast (during which you may be somewhat of a hazard to yourself or bystanders).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Spehro said. The video explicitly says that the machine uses an inverted pendulum principle to control the wheels. What this means is that it has a very sensitive vertical sensor in the body. When you push (even very lightly) forward on the top of the machine, it senses the resulting tip, and drives the wheels forward to get the bottom of the unit directly under the top. This is like a hanging body, which will move the bottom to get under the top if the top is moved. Except, of course, that top and bottom are reversed, which is why it's call an inverted pendulum.